# Acceder a los elementos que se encuentran en todas las listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, estadística

Tengo un diccionario de entradas semanales de fútbol y me gustaría conseguir la tasa de WAU (Weekly Average Users)/MAU (Monthly Average Users) para las participantes femenina. Es por decir el ratio de los participantes que viene cada semana sobre el ratio de los usuarios que vienen al menos una vez en el mes:

```
participants = {
  {
      "date": "2-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Pierre-Irénée Perrin", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Ivanne Combe Laboissière", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Domitille Croizier des Hormais", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Blanche d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Augustin Debouy", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Pierrick Vignon", "sex":"m"}
      ]
  },
  {
      "date": "9-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Clotilde Grange", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Domitille Croizier des Hormais", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Blanche d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Humbert Frécon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Willy DM", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Aude Simonin", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Pierrick Vignon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Andrea Radici", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Stanislas Dupuis", "sex":"m"}
        ]
  },
    {
      "date": "16-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Clotilde Grange", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Willy DM", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Aude Simonin", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Louma Kaa", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Alexandre de Marne", "sex":"m"}
        ]
  },
  {
      "date": "16-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Clotilde Grange", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Willy DM", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Aude Simonin", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Louma Kaa", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Alexandre de Marne", "sex":"m"}
        ]
  },
  {
      "date": "23-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Willy DM", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Louma Kaa", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Alexandre de Marne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Guilhem de Montaignac", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "François Lafon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Humbert Frécon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Matthieu Moussiegt", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Augustin Debouy", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Tanguy Nodet", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Olivier Péneau", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Pierrick Vignon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Arthur Letombe", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Camille Marande", "sex":"f"}
        ]
  },
  {
      "date": "30-6-2021",
      "joueurs": [
            {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
            {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Emile Fleury", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Alexandre de Marne", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "François Lafon", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Félix Di Stasio", "sex":"m"},
            {"name": "Aymeric de Rouvray", "sex":"m"}
        ]
  }
 }
```

De momento sólo sé encontrar a las jugadoras femininas por partido:

```
wau = [y for y in x["joueurs"] for x in matchs if y["sex"] =="f"]
```

Entonces como acceder a los elementos que se encuentran en todas las listas? ¿Así como la proporción de ese número dividido entre todas las jugadoras?

Answer (score 1):

Al venir la estructura en un diccionario, lo más fácil es pasarlo a `Pandas` ya que los diccionarios es la estructura que utiliza `Pandas` para crear sus `DataFrames`. Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []

for participant in participants:
    df = pd.DataFrame(participant["joueurs"])
    df["date"] = participant["date"]
    df_list.append(df)

df_jugadores = pd.concat(df_list)
```

**Salida:**

```
    name    sex date
0   Pierre-Irénée Perrin    m   2-6-2021
1   Ivanne Combe Laboissière    f   2-6-2021
2   Domitille Croizier des Hormais  f   2-6-2021
3   Ombeline d'Harcourt f   2-6-2021
4   Blanche d'Harcourt  f   2-6-2021
               ...
```

Una vez lo tienes en estructura `DataFrame` ya puedes operar los resultados de forma más sencilla, sin necesidad de tener que operar y crear funciones para diccionarios, que es más tedioso.